# Split random integer into 4 random bytes

Tags: c#, .net, random

Can you split a random unsigned integer into 4 random unsigned bytes so that their values (0-255) are uniformly distributed? if so, how?

i tried this in C# but it seems 0 is used more often than other numbers.

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(u);
```

which seems to be doing this:

```
byte[] array = new byte[4];
fixed (byte* ptr = array)
{
    *(int*)ptr = value;
}
return array;
```

here are some of the random integers:
http://pastebin.com/sDWBqKJK

Comment: If your distribution is off that's likely an issue with how you're generating the integer.

Comment: the unsigned integer is provided by a thrid party and is at least supposed to be uniformly distributed.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @AgentFire: about 245/255 of the bytes are 0 instead of 1/255

Comment: why not generate the four bytes randomly rather than the integer as that is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @clamp then your integer is not "distributed" enough.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the source is uniformly distributed within the entire range, as with the above it certainly should produce a uniform distribution of bytes (but not a normal distribution, which is entirely different).

Comment: @Vman because the third party source only provides unsigned integers and i want to get the most out of it as possible without any waste

Comment: @JonHanna if i look at the integer values before splitting it to bytes they seem to be very well uniformly distributed (made a test with 10000)

Comment: I'd prefer bitshifts over `BitConverter`. But from your description it seems like the input is not uniform.

Comment: @clamp Why use a third party source in the first place? Why not simply use a good PRNG seeded by true random value?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: right, i meant uniformly. the decision to use this specific source of random numbers is not up to me.

Comment: Post the rest of your code. The bug is in your code and not in the part you've shown so far.

Comment: @clamp Based on your test data, I think your byte-splitting must be wrong. I get bytes with a mean around 127.

Comment: Just ran `s.Split(new[]{'\r'}).Select(uint.Parse).SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes)` on the example data you provided. It didn't output many zeros.

Comment: Are you using a Memory stream? It's default capacity is 256, which could cause your issue if you use it incorrectly.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: no, actually the problem is already "solved". it has been proven that the problem is in another part of my code (which i have yet to find).

Comment: @scragar: i dont get if you are being ironic or not ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `u` consists of random bits only, including the most significant bit or byte, then your code will work as-is. On the CLR a `uint` has exactly 4 bytes, each of which is 8 bits long. This will work.

It doesn't work so your source of random numbers is faulty. Print 100 of them in hex format (`ToString("X8")`) to the console. You will probably see that there are a lot more zeroes than should be.

Fix the source of random numbers.

Comment: actually they seem not to have that many zeros: B533B3B9
885BC79E
3D20169E
250D69E6
DA57ECBC
8ACA5BE9
8D90869E
67EFDD63
2AF7D7F3
045D0E57
2415A5D3
AADEAA9E
DEB242DA
4C737AA0
20F3C250
E408B658
2DA7E619
3D84634F
EF66EF25
4A15B7A6

Comment: I cannot spot any problems with those numbers, either. `u` is of type `uint` or `int`, right? Try `BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)u)` to be 100% sure. If this does not help your interpretation of the output of `GetBytes` is probably wrong. This will work, this method is not buggy. How are you counting the zeroes? Try printing to the console `BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)u)[0]`. Should look fine. Try the other indexes as well.

Comment: you are right, now the bytes seem fine. i must have an error in another place then!

Comment: @clamp glad I could help you. Regard this as a lesson learned in debugging. Instead of staring at the code waiting for a revelation we investigated actively and verified all components of the system.